# how to mock remote-config from @react-native-firebase/remote-config

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, react-native-firebase

I am trying to mock the ***remote-config*** module from the npm library ***@react-native-firebase/remote-config*** however, I keep getting this error back. I have attempted to mock it below but obviously, it must be incorrect I am just unsure of what is incorrect

```
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: (0 , _remoteConfig.default)(...).setDefaults is not a function
```

```
jest.mock("@react-native-firebase/remote-config", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: () => ({
    remoteConfig: jest.fn(() => ({
      setDefaults: jest.fn(),
    })),
  }),
}));
```

```
import remoteConfig from '@react-native-firebase/remote-config';

// set defaults
remoteConfig().setDefaults(firebaseRemoteConfig);

// fetch remote config
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct way to write the test case for remote-config.

```
jest.mock("@react-native-firebase/remote-config", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: () => ({
    setDefaults: jest.fn(),
  }),
}));
```

Comment: Nice and precise, this worked for me thank you.